# slice the array with pair and without pair in php

Tags: php, slice

The array values are:

```
$input_array = array( "Student_1","Student_2","Student_3","Student_4","student_5","Student_6","Student_7","Student_8" );
```

Now, I need the output as:

```
$array = array( array('Student_1', 'Student_2'), array('Student_3', 'Student_4'),
  array('Student_5', 'Student_6'),  array('Student_7'),  array('Student_8') );
```

Comment: how would you know if the value should be sliced with or without a pair?

Comment: Use words to describe how you want to arrive at that output.

Comment: check array_chunk function

Answer (score 1):

Since you didnt specify your formatting or output rules, I'll just assume the rules myself for this case.

I assume you want your array to take two inputs each from the first and pair them

> array('Student_1', 'Student_2'),

But the last two are not paired

> array('Student_7'), array('Student_8')

So i assume you want the last two to be seperate.
Now for the solution

NOTE: This only works for even arrays for the moment. Working on a more general answer now.

---

```
// We make a new array which takes every two elements from the first and appends to itself
for($i=0; $i < count($input_array)-2; $i=$i+2)
{
$array_output []= array($input_array[$i], $input_array[$i+1]);  //append the teo elements
}

// Now add the final two elements to the array
$array_output []= array($input_array[count($input_array)-2]);
$array_output []= array($input_array[count($input_array)-1]);

//Output here
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array_temp);
echo "</pre>";
```

---

In case if you are new to php

```
$array []= "something"; // will append to the array
```

---

If you didn't want the last two to be seperate (assuming you made a typo),

change

```
for($i=0; $i < count($input_array)-2; $i=$i+2)
```

to

```
for($i=0; $i <= count($input_array); $i=$i+2)
```

and remove

```
/*
$array_output []= array($input_array[count($input_array)-2]);
$array_output []= array($input_array[count($input_array)-1]);
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$input_array = array("Student_1","Student_2","Student_3","Student_4","student_5","Student_6","Student_7","Student_8");
function sliceArray($arr, $pairs = 3){
    $rtnArr = array();
    $total = count($arr);
    if($total < ($pairs * 2)) return 'Error: Invalid number of pairs!';
    for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++){
         if(count($rtnArr) < $pairs && isset($arr[$i+1])){ $rtnArr[] = array($arr[$i], $arr[$i+1]); $i++; }
         else $rtnArr[] = array($arr[$i]);
    }

    return $rtnArr;
}

var_dump(sliceArray($input_array));
```

You can change the $pair value to get required number of pairs.